# Details in proof for convergence of Expectation Maximization Algorithm

Tags: expectation-maximization

I am going through the paper provided here
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dgovinda/pdf/recog/EM_algorithm-1.pdf

I could not make out how the following was derived

$\sum_z \mathcal P(\mathbf z|X, \theta_n)  \ln \big( \frac{\mathcal P(X| \mathbf z, \theta)\mathcal P(z |\theta)}{\mathcal P(\mathbf z|X, \theta_n)}\big ) - \ln\mathcal P(X|\theta_n)$

=$\sum_z \mathcal P(\mathbf z|X, \theta_n)  \ln \big( \frac{\mathcal P(X| \mathbf z, \theta)\mathcal P(z |\theta)}{\mathcal P(\mathbf z|X, \theta_n) \mathcal P(X|\theta_n)}\big ) $

Considering that the left summation in first equation has several terms how is $\ln \mathcal P(X|\theta_n)$ distributed over it?

Comment: I think there might be a typo if you check with formula **(10)**

Comment: i think we need to apply distribution before Jensen's inequality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't that simply that
$$\sum_z\mathcal P(z|X,θ_n)=1$$
and hence that
\begin{align*}
\sum_z &\mathcal P(\mathbf z|X, \theta_n)  \ln \left( \frac{\mathcal P(X| \mathbf z, \theta)\mathcal P(z |\theta)}{\mathcal P(\mathbf z|X, \theta_n)}\right ) - \ln\mathcal P(X|\theta_n)\\
&= \sum_z \mathcal P(\mathbf z|X, \theta_n)  \ln \left( \frac{\mathcal P(X| \mathbf z, \theta)\mathcal P(z |\theta)}{\mathcal P(\mathbf z|X, \theta_n)}\right ) - \sum_z \mathcal P(\mathbf z|X, \theta_n)  \ln\mathcal P(X|\theta_n)\\&=\sum_z \mathcal P(\mathbf z|X, \theta_n)  \ln \left( \frac{\mathcal P(X| \mathbf z, \theta)\mathcal P(z |\theta)}{\mathcal P(\mathbf z|X, \theta_n) \mathcal P(X|\theta_n)}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Would be useful to add that this works because ln P(X|theta_n) doesn't have z and can be put outside of sum

Comment: Not really.....

Comment: Then how the sum is same as without it? Could you elaborate?

Comment: I believe it is due to the law of total probability